# How to get image from white circle overlay with custom camera activity?

Tags: java, android

I am in very big trouble.

I need to implement custom camera functionality what exactly i want to do that i want crop image according to overlays image area in camera activity.

[Please have look image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaIoD.jpg)

In Camera screen image will show with circle overlays than if i press capture button it will take only circle part of image area and saved in sdcard.

Comment: I have seen your screenshot. Check this https://github.com/albinmathew/PhotoCrop. It will help to you .

Comment: Thanks Piyush...it mights helps me

Answer (score 1):

To crop the circle you can use a library called OpenCV which will let you perform functions on the frame you get from the camera.

Eg http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2014/02/crop-elliptical-region-from-image.html

To Find out the coordinates of the region you need to crop you should get the coordinates of the overlay with respect to the frame resolution or the display widget that you are using to display it.
You can get exact coordinates of where the user is placing the circle through Motion Events.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using `Android Studio` for developing you can import this library .

Add the following to your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
}
```

Example would be

```
<com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/photo1"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:riv_corner_radius="30dip"
    app:riv_border_width="2dip"
    app:riv_border_color="#333333"
    app:riv_mutate_background="true"
    app:riv_tile_mode="repeat"
    app:riv_oval="true" />
```

Please check [this](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView) for further info

Comment: Instead of <ImageView> you have to use <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView />

Comment: Please let me know if you're still in trouble. i can help you by providing example if you need.